# What is causing Guid to change value on assignment?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a Solution in vs2010 containing 3 Projects -
Business Objects,
API,
Web App.

The Business Objects are populated from SQLServer using raw ADO and serialized across the various tiers using CSLA. The Web App and API both have a project reference to the Business Objects.

One particular Business Object contains a Guid, populated from ADO to a private field and accessed via a public getter ie read only. When I use it via the web app it works correctly, when I access it via the api and try to do anything with it is always populated with the value `00000000-0260-0251-6002-510200000000`.

Debugging the service call shows the property correctly populated with the value I would expect from the db (hovering over the property, using immediate window, quickwatch etc) however if I try to assign this guid to another variable or pass it as a parameter into another method the passed or assigned value always turns into `00000000-0260-0251-6002-510200000000`.

Every other guid on the business object (there are many) works fine, they are all retrieved and accessed in the same way. Irrespective of which object I load or even which database I connect to, this one property on this one bus object always assigns this value.

This is in Dev & Debug mode, it isn't the debugger getting confused. I've even built it on our TFS build server and deployed the resulting API dll on a separate application server. Same result, so it can't be anything to do with specifically building or running on my dev machine.

I've messed around with parsing to and from string and byte array in the various Guid constructors. Same result. I've been into the MSIL and the call to assign the guid looks the same as every other call to assign a Guid. Nothing unusual. Debugging the Business Object load from the db looks fine and as I say, the value is what I expect until I try to do something with it. The property is as simple as you can get - literally just a return _privateField, no special processing or anything. It works fine via the web app and they are pointing to the same dll!

Googling "`00000000-0260-0251-6002-510200000000`" yields nothing - it doesn't seem to have any special meaning.

Pretty much at my wits end with this, I can't think of any more options to explore. Can anyone think what might be happening here or does `00000000-0260-0251-6002-510200000000` mean anything to anyone?

Comment: Could you please add a **minimal** code example that reproduces the problem?